# WSDL Error while checking for Apex Specialist superbadge challenge

Tags: apex, exception, wsdl, trailhead, superbadges

I am working on Apex Specialist super badge. While doing second challenge it is giving below error :

> There was an unhandled exception. Please reference ID: CTZYSSRH.
>   Error: Faraday::ClientError. Message: INVALID_FIELD: where name = 'UPS
>   3000 VA' and Maintenance_Cycle__c = 180 and Lifespan_Months__c ^ ERROR
>   at Row:1:Column:56 No such column 'Maintenance_Cycle__c' on entity
>   'Product2'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to
>   append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your
>   WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Below is my code :

```
    public with sharing class WarehouseCalloutService {
    private static final String WAREHOUSE_URL = 'https://th-superbadge-apex.herokuapp.com/equipment';
    @Future(callout=true)
    public static void runWarehouseEquipmentSync(){
        List<Product2> lstOfEqup = new List<Product2>();
        
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(WAREHOUSE_URL);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200){
            List<Json2Apex> lstOfEquipments = (List<Json2Apex>) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), List<Json2Apex>.class);
            
            for(Json2Apex inst : lstOfEquipments){
                Product2 prod = new Product2();
                prod.Anonymous_App__Cost__c = inst.cost;
                prod.Anonymous_App__Lifespan_Months__c = inst.lifespan;
                prod.Anonymous_App__Maintenance_Cycle__c= inst.maintenanceperiod;
                prod.Name = inst.name;
                prod.Anonymous_App__Current_Inventory__c = inst.quantity;
                prod.Anonymous_App__Replacement_Part__c = inst.replacement;
                prod.Anonymous_App__Warehouse_SKU__c = inst.sku;
                lstOfEqup.add(prod);
                
                System.debug('cost'+inst.cost);
                System.debug('sku'+inst.sku);
                System.debug('maintenanceperiod'+inst.maintenanceperiod);
            }
        }
        
        if(lstOfEqup != null && lstOfEqup.size() > 0){
            System.debug('lstOfEqup'+lstOfEqup);
            UPSERT lstOfEqup Anonymous_App__Warehouse_SKU__c;
        }
    }
    
    //Wrapper class for Responce details.
    private class Json2Apex{
        private String id;
        private Integer cost;
        private Integer lifespan;
        private Integer maintenanceperiod;
        private String name;
        private Integer quantity; 
        private boolean replacement;
        private String sku;          
    }
}
```

In my org, Namespaces are enabled. I am stuck at this error. Not able to understand what to do. [image]

Comment: Seems like your org that you are validating against has a namespace configured. That will cause all sorts of problems with the validation. I'd suggest starting again against a fresh org and not using a namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is the Anonymous_app__ prefix on your field names on Product2.  I went back and checked the org I completed this badge in and none of the custom fields contained this prefix.  I suspect that when you are trying to complete the challenge trailhead is making assert calls using just Maintenance_cycle__c instead of Anonymous_app__Maintenance_cycle__c and that is the error that is being thrown as a result.

Comment: I have tried it using Maintenance_cycle__c, but still the error is same. @consulps

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, it appears you have [a namespace configured in the org](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=register_namespace_prefix.htm&type=5) you are trying to validate against. This will cause problems with the validation code that Trailhead runs. It won't be able to resolve the field names due to the `Anonymous_App__` prefix.

You will need to create a new org to perform the validation against.